# PHP data from table where todays date is in a range of two fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `orders` with `orderID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, etc.

I want to find if today's date falls within `StartDate` and `EndDate`.  As a starting point I want to print the result that apply

This is my code I just cannot make it work. Also, `CURDATE()` does not work for me.

```
 <?php
    //$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
    //$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

 include "dbh.php";

   $today = DATE("Y-m-d");
    // WHERE $today > StartDate OR $today < EndDate OR $today > SuspendEnd 
 OR $today < SuspendStart";

   //{
     //  echo $today;
   //}


    $sql= "SELECT * FROM orders 
    WHERE $today = StartDate
    ";

    $records = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>".$row['OrderID']."</td>";
        //echo "<td>".$row['StartDate']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Please, edit your code... as it is, it doesn't make sense, like you cut and pasted some text out of place. Adding the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `orders` table will also help.

Comment: Where do you use `CURDATE()`?

Comment: `$today` in your code is a string which should be quoted, as is mysql is subtracting the year from the month from the day. Try `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE curdate() between datestart and dateend`

Comment: I've done some basic cleanup. Please [edit] your question to explain more clearly what isn't working. Ideally, you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I dont have mysql running to test this out but you can try

```
select orderID from orders where (CURDATE() between StartDate and EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following SQL query to get all orders current:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN StartDate AND coalesce(EndDate, CURRENT_DATE) ;
```

It uses the fact that MySQL already has a function to represent "today" (so, you don't need to pass today's value from PHP). If your "EndDate" can be NULL, and you want it to mean "never ends", using `COALESCE` to today's date will make the previous query work.

Check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=88d77407aa8158a3f1013f714d2faf9b)*

---

References:

- [CURRENT_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)
- [... BETWEEN ... AND ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)
- [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)